# Not able to publish sumbit App on Windows Store even all the details are fulfilled

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-store-apps, publish

I am going to sumbit my app on Windows Store. To do this, I have viewed few videos and reference given on the web. Even I have filled up all the information, I am not able to publish the app as "Store Listing" shows "In Complete" status.

I have attached screenshot. 
[image: How to complete this step]
Can anybody please suggest what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the "English (United Kingdom)" link under "Store Listings" and fill in the required fields and provide the required screenshots. The this item will turn into "Complete" and you can submit your app package to the Store certification pipeline.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. From this I complete my step and available now it's available for store listing.